# How to select App from google play store using code in my app?

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an app in which I have got a gallery. When I click on a gallery item, I should go to Google Play and select an app (say for eg Angry Birds) and then download it if i want. How to do this using code? To be precise, I want to go to Google play by clicking an item from the gallery. I have searched a lot but I didnt get it. (how to go to Google Play Store just by clicking a button or anything else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String desiredAppId = "com.rovio.angrybirds";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id="+desiredAppId));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Intent` with correct URI format. The code could look like this

```
String packageName = "com.example.someapp";
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+packageNAme)));
```

More details: [Linking to apps on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html).